# Box Cox transformation in multiple regression using car package in R

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, residuals, jacobian

Could you please confirm that my aproache is right.
In my regression model:

```r
m <- lm(FMI_W ~ IG_WD + SEX + MOTHER_BMI_W +  
        MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES, data = df_adolescent)
```

Response variable is fat mass index. Predictors are IG_WD (metric for physical activity in weekdays) and others. The _W means winsorized data, because of outliers affecting the model.

I have found that this model is inappropriate because of violating the normality assumption and also homogeneity.

I decided to use BoxCox transformation. My process is as follows:

Definition of the lambda with car package:

```r
 bc <- with(df_adolescent, boxCox(FMI_W ~ IG_WD + SEX + MOTHER_BMI_W 
            + MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES, data = df_adolescent,  
            family = "yjPower"))

lambda <- bc$x[which.max(bc$y)]
```

`family = "yjPower"` is set to allow negative response.

After definition of lambda I use one of these syntaxes with function *bcPower* or *yjPower* but I am not sure which one is right. They give a little bit different results as shown. The most visible is intercept value:

```r
> ynew <- lm(bcPower(FMI_W, lambda, jacobian.adjusted = TRUE) ~ 
             IG_WD + SEX + MOTHER_BMI_W + 
             MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES, data = df_adolescent) 
> summary(ynew)

Call:
lm(formula = bcPower(FMI_W, lambda, jacobian.adjusted = TRUE) ~ 
    IG_WD + SEX + MOTHER_BMI_W + MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES, 
    data = df_adolescent)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9492 -1.2414  0.0052  1.1841  4.7098 

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 -1.75531    1.32415  -1.326  0.18588    
IG_WD                       -1.67098    0.52433  -3.187  0.00157 ** 
SEX                          2.14189    0.20248  10.578  < 2e-16 ***
MOTHER_BMI_W                 0.12176    0.02817   4.323 2.03e-05 ***
MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES  0.05538    0.20457   0.271  0.78677    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.778 on 333 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3556,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3478 
F-statistic: 45.93 on 4 and 333 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> ynew1 <- lm(yjPower(FMI_W, lambda, jacobian.adjusted = TRUE) ~ IG_WD + SEX + MOTHER_BMI_W + MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES, data = df_adolescent)
> summary(ynew1)

Call:
lm(formula = yjPower(FMI_W, lambda, jacobian.adjusted = TRUE) ~ 
    IG_WD + SEX + MOTHER_BMI_W + MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES, 
    data = df_adolescent)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.7364 -1.3383 -0.1024  1.1737  4.9443 

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  1.62810    1.32829   1.226  0.22117    
IG_WD                       -1.68276    0.52598  -3.199  0.00151 ** 
SEX                          2.10741    0.20312  10.375  < 2e-16 ***
MOTHER_BMI_W                 0.12491    0.02825   4.421 1.33e-05 ***
MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES  0.03761    0.20521   0.183  0.85471    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.783 on 333 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3514,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3436 
F-statistic:  45.1 on 4 and 333 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I am not sure which one is right and I wasn't able to find it in the R documentation. The only difference seems to be that *bcPower* is able to define gamma but other than that?

I'm setting the "jacobian.adjusted = TRUE" as it should give me the estimate back in the original scale if I understand it right. Is it good assumption?

Comment: These are good questions--but it will be too confusing to try to address them all in one place.  Please edit your post to focus on a single definite question.  If, after reading answers, you have follow-up questions, you can always ask them in new threads.

Comment: @whuber thank you for comment. As I'm new to this forum excuse my post please. Is it better now?

Comment: Re "However when I use log or sqrt or similar method I am unable to transform the estimate back because it's [a] negative value which... isn't possible." This is confusing: although it is not possible (in this context) to take the log or square root of a negative value, *once you have applied such an operation* (to a non-negative number), it's simple to reverse it.  What, then, are you trying to tell us?

Comment: @whuber I guess that information wasn't necessary. But i meant that I used the formula as log(response) ~ predictors. Therefore the estimates are in logged scale but are negative so I cannot use the exp(estimae) function.

Comment: But that's not true, for the reason I gave.  For instance, $\exp(-1) = 1/e \approx 0.37.$ Perhaps your question might be resolved by reviewing properties of logarithms and exponentials?

Comment: @whuber I might have explained it wrong but I expect that the physical activity reduce fat mass index. So in additive case when IG_WD increase by 1 unit the FMI_W decrease by estimated value. However when I get ie. estimate of -0.233 for IG_WD on logged scale the back-transformation is exp(-0.233)  = 0.7921. Which doesn't seem right. If I fit the model without any transformation I get estimate of IG_WD about -1.9 which can be pretty rought but I don't think it would change so hard from positive to negative. Or I am interpreting the whole regression wrongly?

Comment: It's impossible to tell whether the -0.233 estimate makes sense without knowing how IG_WD is measured.  It would *really* help to reduce your problem to a small, clear example so you can explain the data and focus on what matters.