# Interpreting multiple regression with transformed response variable

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, regression-coefficients, normality-assumption, back-transformation

I have build regression model focused on association between physical activity and fat mass. The model is as follows:

```r
model <- lm(FMI_W ~ IG_WD + SEX + MOTHER_BMI_W + MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES, data = df_adolescent)
```

Where FMI_W = Fat mass index winsorized, IG_WD = novel metric from accelerometers which is reflecting negative drop in intensity of physical activity as time increase and is always negative.

However this model is violating the assumptions of normality and homogeneity of residuals. As result I decided to log transform the respons variable as it improves residuals of the model. But now I am having problems with interpretation.

The model and results are following:

```r
> model <- lm(log(FMI_W) ~ IG_WD + SEX + MOTHER_BMI_W + MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES, data = df_adolescent)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = log(FMI_W) ~ IG_WD + SEX + MOTHER_BMI_W + MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES, 
    data = df_adolescent)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.18164 -0.32438 -0.01599  0.28784  1.20763 

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 -0.601001   0.326940  -1.838   0.0669 .  
IG_WD                       -0.414468   0.129461  -3.201   0.0015 ** 
SEX                          0.520450   0.049994  10.410  < 2e-16 ***
MOTHER_BMI_W                 0.030605   0.006954   4.401 1.45e-05 ***
MOTHER_EDUCATION_CATEGORIES  0.010488   0.050510   0.208   0.8356    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4389 on 333 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3521,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3443 
F-statistic: 45.23 on 4 and 333 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Could you please help me with back transformation of estimate of IG_WD. For me it doesn't make sence to use exp(-0.414468) = 0.6606917 as the exponential result is positive value but according to what we know about physical activity it should decrease fat mass.

If I use the model with violating the assumptions so without the log transformation I get estimate around -1.9 for IG_WD.

Also I have tried BoxCox transformation as is in this post [Box Cox transformation in multiple regression using car package in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/513384/313504)

---

Actualization:
The FMI_W is a shortcut for fat mass index which is equvivalent of $FMI = fat mass(kg)/height^2(m)$. _W stands for winsorzed data to reduce outliers.
Summary of FMI_W:

```r
> summary(df_adolescent$FMI_W)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.532   2.648   4.111   4.634   6.202   9.875
```

Distrubution of FMI_W can be seen on next plot:
[image]

As suggested in the comments. Would be the glm with gamma family link = "identical" appropriate?

Comment: It's difficult to tell much about your response variable FMI_W. Could you tell us more about this please. Maybe you could use a generalized linear model instead of transforming - it is generally preferred.

Comment: A plot (histogram or density) of the untransformed response variable could be helpful for helpers to see. `hist(FMI_W)`  or  `plot(density(FMI_W))` for example. Agree with rw2, that often an alternative model can fix these issues. Also, I note that the outcome and a covariate (BMI) contain subject height^2. This can cause issues because you can have part of the model asking something like "does height predict height?".

Comment: As for understanding the model, your covariates are predicting changes in the log(FMI_W). For example, if SEX is 1 for male and 0 for female, then you might interpret as "On average, and after accounting for the other variables in the model, men have a log(FMI_W) that is 0.52 times that of women" (i.e. half). So if the log(FMI_W) is 0.52 as big, this means that FMI_W is e^(0.52) = 1.68 times as big.

Comment: @BrantInman You are right that covariate BMI contains height^2 but of mother. So it would be like "does height of mother predict height of child in adolescent age"
As for your second comment you are right too but in SEX 1 is for female and it's known fact that women do have more fat mass. But wouldn't it be interpretid as that female does have on average larger FMI_W by 1.68?

Comment: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-regression-coefficients/

Comment: @BrantInman I am sorry if I am missing something or is it by that I am not a native speaker  but in the equation ie. $Y = B0 + B1*X1  + Bn*Xn + e$ SEX would be represeting as this: $Y = B0 + 1.68*1 + Bn*Xn + e$ for female and as this: $Y = B0 + 1.68*0 + Bn*Xn + e$ for male. Not as $Y*1.68$ ... or at least this is how I'm interpreting your comment. Anyway I would say this is different kind of question not exatctly related mine.